# Diagonalize large matrix with python on GPU?

Tags: python, gpu

I want to Diagonalize some large matrices ( the largest one is 25K x 25K) on GPU with python. Is there some recommendation how to do this? I am already using CUDA for some other stuff - maybe it will be helpful?

Comment: you maybe want to check out pytorchs (or tensorflows) features. There are things like "torch.diagonal()" or torch.diag_embed()". You can pass a tensor on gpu as input. Check them out, I dont know what they do exactly

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm currently diagonalizing hundreds of matrices ( about 2K x 2K each) using the CPU and was wondering if I could speed up the process using a GPU.

Comment: @LucasBaldo no unfortunately not